# Употребление местоимений

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "те, что приходят", если речь идет о людях? Или обязательно надо заменить на "те, кто приходит"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Местоимение ЧТО является универсальным и может использовать в предложениях с одушевленными лицами, при выборе ЧТО/КТО учитывается форма числа для глагола-сказуемого.

Вариант 1. Те, что приходят.

При использовании местоимения ЧТО сказуемое может иметь форму мн. числа, что соответствует грамматическому согласованию по форме.

Те, что были с лопатами, принялись подкапывать его снизу (Василь Быков).

А те, что катаются в таких чудных бричках со стеклами... (Н. В. Гоголь).

Вариант 2. Те, кто приходит.  В этом случае естественным выглядит согласование в ед. числе.

Его беспокоят те, кто ходит в дождь без шляпы.  Блаженны те, кто это читает, кто слышит слова откровения.

Answer (score 3):

Можно так сказать: здесь "что" имеет не связанное с одушевлённостью значение "которые". Люди опять пришли, но уже не те, *что* вчера приходили.